# Automatically value from type string gets converts to boolean C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm parsing xml file and storing it in a OrderedDictionary datatype with xml tag name as 'key' and its innerXML as 'value'. Things work fine till the values are read and stored in OrderedDictionary variable.

[Screenshot showing Debugger OrderedDictionary values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSeH2.png)

When I try to read the `OrderedDictionary` with `KeyValuePair`, the value of the Key `Fees` is shown as `False` and throws System.InvalidCastException. I know that this is a typecasting issue but my problem is that how the value which is stored as 'string' got converted to 'boolean'.

[Image hyperlink - KeyValuePair shows `Fees` as `False`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKHgO.png)

This is a small snippet of code that handles this task:

```
for (int j = 0; j < intXmlRecordFieldCount; j++) {
XmlTagname = xmlRootNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[j].Name.ToString().Trim();
xmlTagInnerValue = xmlRootNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerXml.ToString().Trim();
DictXmlRecordColumns.Add(XmlTagname, xmlTagInnerValue);
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in DictXmlRecordColumns) {
    string xmlTagName = kvp.Key;
    string xmlInnerValue = kvp.Value;
    DataRow[] resultset= dsResult.Tables[0].Select("ColumnName='"+xmlTagName+"'");
    Console.WriteLine(resultset.Length);
    if (Int32.Parse(xmlInnerValue) >= MinValue&& Int32.Parse(xmlInnerValue) <= MaxValue) {
        string QueryParamColumnNames = null;
        string QueryParamColumnValues = null;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> SqlQueryParams in SqlQueryParams) {
                QueryParamColumnNames += SqlQueryParams.Key.Trim() + ',';
                QueryParamColumnValues += convertToSqlParams(SqlQueryParams.Value.Trim()) + ',';
        }
    QueryParamColumnValues = QueryParamColumnValues.TrimEnd(',');
    sqlInsertQueries.Add("INSERT INTO " + dbTableName + " (" + QueryParamColumnNames + ") values( " + QueryParamColumnValues + ")");
}
```

This is the sample xml which I'm intending to parse

```
<studentrecords>
<STUDENT_RECORDS>
    <RollNumber>1</RollNumber>
    <Name>Akshay</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Fees>900.00</Fees>
</STUDENT_RECORDS>

<STUDENT_RECORDS> 
    <RollNumber>2</RollNumber>
    <Name>Alex</Name>
    <Age>8</Age>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Fees>900.00</Fees>
</STUDENT_RECORDS>

</studentrecords>
```

Can anyone help me regarding  this issue?

Edit(1): I wanted `Fees` to be fetched as `900.00` but how it gets converted to boolean. Any ways through which I can avoid this?

Edit(2): Added XML Sample

Comment: Seems like you have boolean column in database and you are trying to insert string value `"False"` instead of boolean `False`. You don't need quotes around numbers or booleans

Comment: Try inserting booleans with '0' and '1' to evade mistakes

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Bro, but I'm not involving any query. I'm just taking it from one variable to another. No db operations involved

Comment: QueryParamColumnNames = SqlQueryParams.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray(); string ColumnNames = string.Join(",",QueryParamColumnNames);QueryParamColumnValues = SqlQueryParams.Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).ToArray(); string ColumnValues = string.Join(",",QueryParamColumnValues);

Comment: Are those two screenshots from the same moment in time? A dictionary entry holding a value of 900 is not going to be changed to "false" unless you do something to change it. So stepping through with the debugger line by line and keeping an eye on things until it changes is the best way for you to understand where it is changing and why.

Comment: @Chris yes the screenshots are exactly taken at the same moment

Comment: Could you add the actual XML that you parse? Without it we have to guess at what it looks like...

Comment: Yeah, I think producing code that we could run to recreate the problem would help a lot which means including the XML you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by fixing the line of code 
`foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in DictXmlRecordColumns)` to 
`foreach (DictionaryEntry de in DictXmlRecordColumns)` as stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx).
And it worked.
Thanks for your time and help everyone.